# How would I loop this code to run everytime a user types "no"

Tags: java

I am coding a text based adventure and have run into a problem running a class system. I have set up a case to run a block of code that will run a method, however both the case and method are running more than once without user input and will not stop running after user input.

I have tried a for loop, a while loop, a do/while loop but nothing has had any profound effect. I do have a theory, I need to implement a case change after the method has run, but I don't know how to do this without making the case change on its own.

Here is the case -

```
case "1.5":

    System.out.println("\nNow, before we start you need to choose a class. Each one will offer diffrent benefits.");
    classes();
    break;
```

Here is the method -

```
public static void classes() { //Class Method
    counter = 0;

    for (int a = 1; a <= Class.length; a++) { //Run the class array
        System.out.println("[" + counter + "]- " + Class[counter]); //displays the class array
        counter++;
    }


    do {
        System.out.println("What would you like to be."); //ask for input
        user = in .nextLine();

        if (user.equals("0")) { //if input is this then ...
            System.out.println("\nYour health will be increased by 1 permanently." +
                "Are you sure you want to be a Farmer?");
            user = in .nextLine();
        }

        if (user.equals("1")) { //if input is this then...
            System.out.println("\nYou will have a dagger." +
                "Are you sure you want to be a Wanderer?");
            user = in .nextLine();
        }

        if (user.equals("2")) { 
            System.out.println("\nYou will have 1 health potion. Drink it to regain 3 HP." +
                "Are you sure you want to be a Trader?");
            user = in .nextLine();
        }

        if (user.equals("3")) {
            System.out.println("You are just a normal human. You get nothing." +
                "Are you sure you want to be nothing?");
            user = in .nextLine();
        }

    } while(user.equalsIgnoreCase("no")); //runs while user types no

}
```

I expect the method to run once and the output to be what the user wants it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I expect the method to run once and the output to be what the user
>   wants it to."

And basically that is exactly what the code does if what you really mean:

> "I expect the method to run once and the output to be what the user
>   wants it to be if he or she enters **yes**".

If the User enters **no** for a selection within the **classes()** method then the User is asked to select another Class until he or she is satisfied with the selection. I believe this is the intention is it not?

I think your problem is that when a User does make a Class selection it stays within the ***classes()*** method. What I believe you really want to do is return that selection and utilize the selection **after** the point where the ***classes()*** method was initially called so as to proceed deeper into the game.

In order to do this you will need your **classes()** method to return something, preferably the Class chosen. Since the different Classes (ranks) are contained within a String Array:

```
static String[] Class = {"Farmer", "Wanderer", "Trader", "Nothing"};
```

All you need returned from the ***classes()*** method is the actual index value of the chosen Class. You can of course have another Class Member variable hold the Users choice....perhaps a variable named: **userClass**. Before we get into that however I would like to make at least two suggestions:

Don't name a variable **Class**. You can do it but to me (and I'm sure many many others) it's confusing and not really a good idea since **class** itself is a [Java Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9). As a suggestion, perhaps change it to something like: **Ranks**.

Give your variables and method names meaning so that it can be easily understood what the variable may hold or what the method will do like perhaps: **getRank()**.

```
// Class Member Variables
static Scanner keyBoardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
static String userInput;
static String userClass = ""; 
static String[] RANKS = {"Farmer", "Wanderer", "Trader", "Nothing"};
static String LS = System.lineSeparator();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("\nNow, before we start you need to choose a class." + LS
                     + "Each Class will offer diffrent benefits.");
    int rank = getRank();
    userClass = RANKS[rank];
    System.out.println("Your chosen Class is:  " + userClass);
}

public static int getRank() {
    int maxRank = (RANKS.length - 1);
    // Displays the RANKS array
    for (int a = 0; a < RANKS.length; a++) { 
        System.out.println("[" + a + "]- " + RANKS[a]); 
    }

    // Allow User to select a Rank
    int rank = -1;
    do {
        System.out.println("What would you like to be? (0 to " + maxRank + 
                           " or q to quit)"); //ask for input
        userInput = keyBoardInput.nextLine();

        // Quit game if desired.
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            System.out.println(LS + "Thanks for playing...Bye Bye.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Make sure a valid numerical value was supplied!
        if (!userInput.matches("\\d") || Integer.parseInt(userInput) < 0 || 
                               Integer.parseInt(userInput) > maxRank) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! You can only supply a value "
                             + "from 0 to " + maxRank); 
            userInput = "no";
            continue;
        }
        rank = Integer.parseInt(userInput); // Store for for array index use and returning
        String message = "";

        // Farmer (0)
        switch (rank) {
            case 0:
                message = LS + "Your health will be increased by 1 permanently.";
                break;
            case 1:
                //if input is this then...
                message = LS + "You will have a dagger.";
                break;
            case 2:
                message = LS + "You will have 1 health potion. Drink it to regain 3 HP.";
                break;
            case 3:
                message = LS + "You are just a normal human. You get nothing.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println("Are you sure you want to be " + RANKS[rank] + "?");
        userInput = keyBoardInput.nextLine();

    } while (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")); //loops while user types no

    return rank;  // Return the index value for the chosen Rank. 
}
```

Notice the variable names and the **getRank()** method name? It's much easier to follow the code and understand what is going on. No, I personally don't really care for static variables and methods. Static's do have a place but I prefer to run code somewhat tighter than this.

You will also notice other changes within the above code. In particular, the **for** loop used to display the Class menu choices:

```
[0]- Farmer
[1]- Wanderer
[2]- Trader
[3]- Nothing
```

You utilize a variable named **counter** and use it for indexing. This is exactly what your **for** loop is used for. You can get rid of the **counter** variable and simply utilize the **a** variable declared within the **for** loop itself.

Take notice how the **switch/case** block is used. How it reduces the code. You will also notice that the **getRank()** method returns the index value of the Class selected by the User. When called from the **main()** method the **getRank()** method returns the Class index value and we place the Class chosen into the member variable **userClass** which you can now use anywhere within your code. Yes, you could of set the **userClass** variable directly within the **getRank()** method as well.

Comment: Alright thank you for the feedback! On mobile right now so I can’t test the code, when I am I’ll post back results and see if that solved the issue. I’ll look up the functions you used to understand it so I Can use it further in my code, I thought I was able to make it with simple functions but apparently not. Thanks again! ;)

Comment: Yeah that did it! I wanted to fully understand what you had written before I tried it. So thanks again!